# What does "Pull up a bit of grass" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> ... ...
>
> "**Pull up a bit of grass**, Barry," said Ludo brightly, patting the ground beside him.
>
> "No thank you, Ludo," said (Barry)Crouch, and there was a bite of impatience
>   in his voice. "I've been looking for you everywhere. The Bulgarians
>   are insisting we add another twelve seats to the Top Box." ...

I think in this context Ludo was asking Barry to sit beside him. The phrase "*Pull up a bit of grass*" is pretty close to "*Pull up a chair*". But does Ludo mean that Barry literally pulled up a bit of grass and sit beside him? How should we understand it in this context?

Comment: I think you are right, it just convey's Ludo's offer. He or she offers Barry to sit next to him.

Comment: Just a side note, @Cardinal, but **offer** when it has an indirect object (e.g. Barry) does not take an infinitive clause complement (to sit).  ...offers Barry *a seat*

Comment: As a side note, what edition of Harry Potter are you using? I'm wondering if your edition actually has the person's name as Barry, or it was just a typo here, because the person's name is actually Bar***t***y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're exactly right--this is a play on *pull up a chair*, which is an invitation to sit. There are no chairs in this scenario, so Ludo offers whatever is next to him: the bit of grass.

Comment: Thanks! So, does Barry have to pull up a bit of grass literally in response to it?

Comment: No, there is no literal pulling of grass. It's a loose metaphor and reads as a very informal invitation to sit, which Crouch refuses.

Comment: To clarify, to "pull up a chair" means to move (pull) a chair over here ("up" in the same sense as to walk *up* to someone, not literally upwards). It's usually meant in the sense of "get a chair so that we can sit together". Obviously, the grass does not need to be moved, which is part of why this phrase is humorous.